# Java server side annotated REST client library

Tags: java, spring, annotations, rest-client

I'm building a middleware service that consumes external REST services (from the server side). I'm currently using Spring boot with RestTemplate to make the remote calls.

```
    Map<String, String> urlVariables = new HashMap<>();
    urlVariables.put("address", IP);
    urlVariables.put("port", PORT);
    urlVariables.put("par1", parameter1);
    urlVariables.put("par2", parameter2);

    MyServiceResponse state =
            restTemplate.getForObject("http://{address}:{port}/service/{par1}/{par2}", MyServiceResponse.class, urlVariables);
```

I was wondering whether there's any library that provides annotations to automatically generate REST clients, like Volley does in Android.

```
@GET(url="http://{address}:{port}/service/{par1}/{par2}")
public MyServiceResponse getCurrentState(String address, String port, String par1, String par2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [RESTEasy Proxy Framework](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#d4e2149):

> Resteasy has a client proxy framework that allows you to use JAX-RS
>   annotations to invoke on a remote HTTP resource. The way it works is
>   that you write a Java interface and use JAX-RS annotations on methods
>   and the interface.

Comment: That looks exactly what I need, now let's see how it works with Spring Boot

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?:

https://github.com/dpalmisano/NoTube-Beancounter-2.0/blob/master/platform/src/main/java/io/beancounter/platform/rai/MyRaiTVService.java#L45

```
@POST
@Path("/login/auth")
public Response loginWithAuth(
        @FormParam("username") String username,
        @FormParam("token") String token

) {
    try {
        Validations.checkNotEmpty(username, "Missing username parameter");
        Validations.checkNotEmpty(token, "Missing MyRaiTV token parameter");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return error(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps you (from code.openhub.net):

http://code.openhub.net/file?fid=tUDx4oQRk7m8Fbf7HmE_8y_W6YQ&cid=8pHdzAiENbA&s=Java%20server%20side%20annotated%20REST%20client%20library&pp=0&fl=Java&ff=1&filterChecked=true&fp=1329&mp,=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&projSelected=true#L0

Answer (score 0):

You can use [REST Gap](https://bitbucket.org/restgap/restgap/wiki/Home) for this. You only need to:

- Have Spring MVC or JAX-RS style annotated interfaces
- Call the REST Gap factory and pass your interface and a RestTemplate instance
- Receive an implementation of your interface that calls your REST Service

This is how it looks in code (for a Spring-MVC interface IPetStoreService):

```
// Create client
IPetStoreService client = RESTTemplateSpringMVCFactory
    .create(restTemplate, "http://mypetstore.com/rest", IPetStoreService.class);

// Call it!
List<Pet> pets = client.listPets();
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but Feign is a pretty good choice.  I've used it in Spring Boot applications which were web services that themselves consumed other internal web services.  It's nice to only need to write a Java interface and annotate it minimally, and have your boilerplate code done for you.

https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign

For more info on Spring integration, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/

Note that the latest Feign requires at least Java 8, but you should be able to obtain a version that supports Java 6 if needed.

I know that Java 11 has an HttpClient which may or may not also suit your needs, but I confess that I don't know much about it yet.